# Passing a vector by const reference with a custom type in C++

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

Say you have the custom type,

```
class Foo {}
```

Is the correct way to pass a vector of type Foo by const reference to a method like this,

```
void f(const std::vector<const Foo&>& bar);
```

or should I do,

```
void f(const std::vector<Foo>& bar);
```

I'm more curious on which one I should prefer to use.

Comment: you can try it. (by *call* `f` somewhere else)

Comment: _"Both seam to compile and work."_ Show me. I don't believe for a second that any code can interchange `vector<Foo>` and `vector<const Foo&>` in a function signature and still compile for the same call site... not that the latter is valid anyway since containers can't contain references.

Answer (score 4):

You should pass `const std::vector<Foo>&` as the type. This prevents a value copy of the vector from being taken when the function is called.

Note that a `std::vector<Foo&>` is not allowed by the current standards: a `std::vector` cannot contain reference types.